# List comprehension on lists within lists

Tags: python

If I create two lists that contain lists like this:

```
bad_list.append(['blue_widget', 'cracked', '776'])
bad_list.append(['red_widget', 'not_smooth', '545']) 
bad_list.append(['yellow_widget', 'spots', '35']) 
bad_list.append(['green_widget', 'smells_bad', '10'])
bad_list.append(['purple_widget', 'not_really_purple', '10'])


good_list.append(['blue_widget', 'ok', '776'])
good_list.append(['red_widget', 'ok', '545']) 
good_list.append(['green_widget', 'ok', '10'])
```

I would love to be able to use list comprehension to compare the two lists and remove
all items in the bad list that are present in the good list using the first element 
(x_widget) as item to compare. Using the example above I should be left with:

```
['yellow_widget', 'spots', '35']
['purple_widget', 'not_really_purple', '10']
```

I have tried using list comprehension and it works but the new list does not retain each line:

```
final_list = [x for x in bad_list[0] if x not in good_list[0]]
```

When I print out the contents using for item in final_list I get something like:

```
yellow_widget
smells_bad
10
```

Any clues would be much appreciated.

Comment: `bad_list[0]` and `good_list[0]` are the first entries of the list, not the first column. — I can’t think of a one-liner to do this at the moment. Probably you have to use a regular `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really optimized by any means, but this should work: http://codecube.io/AD7RHA

```
bad_list=[]
good_list=[]

bad_list.append(['blue_widget', 'cracked', '776'])
bad_list.append(['red_widget', 'not_smooth', '545']) 
bad_list.append(['yellow_widget', 'spots', '35']) 
bad_list.append(['green_widget', 'smells_bad', '10'])
bad_list.append(['purple_widget', 'not_really_purple', '10'])


good_list.append(['blue_widget', 'ok', '776'])
good_list.append(['red_widget', 'ok', '545']) 
good_list.append(['green_widget', 'ok', '10'])

# ['yellow_widget', 'spots', '35']
# ['purple_widget', 'not_really_purple', '10']

labels = zip(*good_list)[0]

new_bad_list=[]

for item in bad_list:
    if item[0] not in labels:
        new_bad_list.append(item)

print new_bad_list
```

or this one-liner:

```
new_bad_list=[item for item in bad_list if item[0] not in zip(*good_list)[0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

One liner

```
[x for x in bad_list if any(x[0] == y[0] for y in good_list)]
```

*thanks @Bakuriu

Comment: Note that you can avoid the list-comprehension for `any`. Simply use a genexp: `any(x[0] == y[0] for y in good_list)`. In this way you avoid the creation of a list. Also `any` short-circuits, so it will be faster in the average case. If the function requires more than an argument you have to enclose the genexp in `(` and `)`, like: `filter(some_function, (x for x in the_genexp))`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
print [ele for ele in bad_list if ele[0] not in [i[0] for i in good_list]]
```

Output:

```
[['yellow_widget', 'spots', '35'], ['purple_widget', 'not_really_purple', '10']]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a more efficient solution. Make a set from your list

```
bad_set = set(bad_list)
good_set = set(good_list)
```

Now to remove all items in the bad list that are present in the good list, you can simple substract the sets:

```
bad_set - good_set
```

Convert set back to list if you like.

Comment: This won't work because the OP has a list of lists, and lists aren't hashable.  I'm sure you meant something like `bad_set = set(x[0] for x in bad_list)` etc..., but you would need more work than just taking the set difference.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way is:

```
final_list = [x for x in bad_list if x[0] not in [x[0] for x in good_list]]
```

but notice that to test an element's existing in a list is not that efficient.

So, you can first build a set:

```
good_list_names = set([x[0] for x in good_list])
```

and then:

```
final_list = [x for x in bad_list if x[0] not in good_list_names]
```